# How I can able to get 2 output by using This();

Tags: java, constructor, this

Is it possible to get the 2 output by using `this();` for this code? I'm not very familiar with `this();` so with an explanation would help me this understand this concept. The output I'm looking for is 222 Morty & 222 Morty 25 or if it's possible to get 111 Rick & 222 Morty 25.

```
class Student5 {  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    int age;  

    public Student5(int i,String n) {  
        id = i;  
        name = n;  
    }  

    public Student5(int i,String n,int a) {
        this(i, n);
        id = i;  
        name = n;  
        age=a;  
    }  

    void display() {
         System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+age);
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        // Student5 s1 = new Student5(111,"Rick");  
        Student5 s2 = new Student5(222,"Morty",25);  
        // s1.display();
        s2.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: in the constructor `public Student5(int i,String n,int a)` you call `this(i, n)`, so you do not need to set the `id` and `name` again.

Comment: what is the "2 output"? there is no This, it's this. It's a keyword, and java is case sensitive. You do have redundant code in your second constructor. Can you spot it? What have you tried so far? where is your actual problem?

Comment: Please explain "Is it possible ". What, precisely, is the problem you are having?

Comment: Yes, what problem are you having?  And you do you envision `this()` helping?

Comment: My problem to get the 2 output by only creating 1 object instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student5{  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    int age;  

public Student5(int i,String n){  
System.out.println(i+" "+n);
    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    }  

public Student5(int i,String n,int a){
this(i, n);
System.out.println(i+" "+n+" "+a);
    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    age=a;  
    }  

void display(){
     System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+age);
   }  


public static void main(String args[]){  
//   Student5 s1 = new Student5(111,"Rick");  
    Student5 s2 = new Student5(222,"Morty",25);  
//   s1.display();
    //s2.display();

   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
 class Student5{  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    int age;  
public Student5(){  

}
public Student5(int i,String n){  
    this();
    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    }  

public Student5(int i,String n,int a){
this(i, n);
    age=a;  
    }  

void display(){
     System.out.println(id+" "+name);
     if(age > 0){
        System.out.print(" "+age );
     }
   }  


public static void main(String args[]){  
   Student5 s1 = new Student5(111,"Rick");  
    Student5 s2 = new Student5(222,"Morty",25);  
   s1.display();
    s2.display();

   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyword **THIS** is a reference variable in Java that refers to the current object.

let understand THIS keyword from an example:

```
class Example {
   int a,b;

   Example(int a, int b) {
       //During execution, the compiler is confused. Whether "a" and "b" on the left side
       //of the assigned operator is the instance variable or the local variable.
       // a=a; 
       // b=b;
       // To overcome this confusion we use THIS keyword to differentiate between
       // instiante variable and parameter varaible.
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
   }
}
```

Secondly, the display method will display values which are assigned to that object. if you want to explicit print only id and name you can create a new display method.

```
void display(){
     System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+age);
} 

void limitDisplay(){
     System.out.println(id+" "+name);
}
```

however, in your case, the only display will also work as no age data found against Rick record.

```
class Student5{  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    int age;  

public Student5(int i,String n){  

    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    }  

public Student5(int i,String n,int a){
    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    age=a;  
    }  

void display(){
     System.out.print(id+" "+name+" ");
     if(age>0) {
         System.out.print(age);
     }
     System.out.println("");
   } 


public static void main(String args[]){  
   Student5 s1 = new Student5(111,"Rick");  
   Student5 s2 = new Student5(222,"Morty",25);  
   s1.display();
   s2.display();

   }  
}
```

> run:
>
> 111 Rick
>
> 222 Morty 25

Answer (score 0):

this refers current object.

When you create object as `new Student5(222,"Morty",25);` it calls the Student5 class constructor which has the params `(int, String, int)` 
i.e `new Student5(int,String,int);`
in your case it is

```
public Student5(int i,String n,int a){
this(i, n);
    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    age=a;  
    }
```

now you can use i, n, a to initialize the  variables.
ofcourse you did it, but you are assigning values twice in below steps

```
this(i, n);
    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    age=a;
```

now change it to

```
public Student5(int i,String n,int a){
   this(i, n); 
    age=a;  
    }
```

here this(i, n) checks the custroctor with Student5(int, String) types.
So, it goes to below code and do initializtion, if you miss the constructor it gives the compilation error.

```
 public Student5(int i,String n){  
        id = i;  
        name = n;  
        }
```

display() prints the output depends upon on which object you are calling the method.

```
Student5 s1 = new Student5(111,"Rick"); 
  s1.display()
```

prints 111 Rick.
      because you are calling teh display on s1 it dont know about the s2 object data

```
Student5 s2 = new Student5(222,"Morty",25);  
s2.display()
```

prints 222 Morty 25

because you are calling teh display on s2 it dont know about the s1 object data

to answer you question " if it's possible to get 111 Rick & 222 Morty 25."

yes you can do it in main method as you have both objects available.
call display method on two objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very helpful.

Comment: you are welcome. please accept my answer if it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is ***no***.

When you create 2 `Student` objects like this:

```
Student5 s1 = new Student5(111,"Rick");  
Student5 s2 = new Student5(222,"Morty",25);
```

They are not linked in any way.
So it is not possible to print the output of s1 `Student` from the `display()` of s2 `Student` like that.

A link could be by way of adding a *buddy* reference on your `Student5`.

```
class Student5 {  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    int age;
    Student5 buddy;

    public Student5(int i,String n) {  
        id = i;  
        name = n;  
    }  

    public Student5(int i,String n,int a) {
        this(i, n);
        age = a;  
    }  

    public void setBuddy(Student5 b) {
        this.buddy = b;
        b.buddy = this;
    }

    private String getInfo() {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        buff.append(id+" "+name);
        if (age > 0)
            buff.append(" "+age );
        return buff.toString();
    }

    public void display() {
        if (buddy != null)
            System.out.println(this.getInfo() +" & "+ buddy.getInfo());
        else
            System.out.println(this.getInfo());
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        Student5 s1 = new Student5(111,"Rick");  
        Student5 s2 = new Student5(222,"Morty",25);

        s2.display();

        s1.setBuddy(s2);

        s1.display();
        s2.display();
    }
}
```

This will print

> 222 Morty 25
>   111 Rick & 222 Morty 25
>   222 Morty 25 & 111 Rick

---

Now about your **`this`** confusion:

- `this` is a Java reference to the current Object from within the Object, like `this.name`
- `this()` is a reference to the parameter-less constructor of the current Object.

Through **constructor overloading** (constructors with different types/number of parameters)
and **constructor chaining** (calling one constructor from another overloaded constructor)
you can avoid repeating code.

A exaggerated example using both `this` and `this()`:

```
public Student5() {
    this.age = 0;
}

public Student5(int i) {  
    this();
    this.id = i;
}

public Student5(int i, String n) { 
    this(i);
    this.name = n;  
}  

public Student5(int i, String n, int a) {
    this(i, n);
    this.age = a;  
}
```

If you call `Student5(222, "Morty", 25)`, the execution chain is the following:

> Student5(222, "Morty", 25)
>   calls constructor -> Student5(222, "Morty")
>   calls constructor -> Student5(222)
>   calls constructor -> Student5() who sets the age to 0
>   returns to Student5(222) who sets the id
>   returns to Student5(222, "Morty") who sets the name
>   returns to Student5(222, "Morty", 25) who sets the age